# My son has his guy stuck in 3rd person on Minecraft, and the left stick will not change the POV. What do I do?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son is playing Minecraft on an Xbox One S, and he is currently stuck in the 3rd person view. I tried looking it up, but everything just said to use the left toggle switch. That, however, is doing nothing. How do I change the POV?

Comment: Can you make a screenshot (or, since it's a console, a photo) or maybe even a video and link it?

Comment: Look in the controls menu - you can also change it in video settings. This is a comment bc i cant be bothered to do a whole writeup thing on it rn

Answer (score 1):

On the Xbox One the correct game control to change the view is  *Press down on Left Stick (LS)*.

Now if that is not working I would recommend restarting the console (Silly I know but simple problems sometimes require the most simple solutions). You could also go into the settings of the game and check the controller controls and see if the key was changed from that. Last of all you could always try plugging in a keyboard and change the POV like that.

[image]
[Image credits go to Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/hands-xbox-one-mouse-and-keyboard-support)

Answer (score -5):

I’m not sure if this will work for you or not, but you could try changing the batteries in the controller and see if that works?

Comment: what is this lol